# Is it possible to enable dm-integrity on an existing LUKS/cryptsetup device?

Tags: luks, disk-encryption, cryptsetup, dm-crypt, whole-drive-encryption

I have a large LUKS2 device created with `cryptsetup` that holds an LVM2 with my root and other filesystems. The device is several TB in size and I don't have any others disks (or combinations of disks) that it could be intermediately copied to.

I recently learned about DM-Integrity and that DM-Crypt has a built-in version of it that can be optionally enabled, and I would like to start using it with my encrypted devices. All of the documentation describes setting it up when the device is created, however, and the `cryptsetup reencrypt` function doesn't seem to mention it.

I would imagine that the integrity info takes up more space than without it, but I have plenty of free space in that regard. I'm willing to settle for DM-Integrity on a separate layer, but would like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: You should describe the current (`lsblk`) and intended setup in more detail.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I can, but it's quite convoluted and would seem to me (from my naive perspective) unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The existing `cryptsetup` encryption is not related to dm-integrity (i.e. you do not have to reencrypt). You need free space for metadata. dm-integrity either works on the block device which you have encrypted (not a good idea unless you set up another encrypted device for the metadata) or on the LVM LVs you have within your LUKS volume.

Have a look at the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/integritysetup.8.html) of `integritysetup`, especially `--data-device`.

Comment: According to the man page: "The dm-integrity target emulates additional data integrity field per-sector. You can use this additional field directly with integritysetup utility, or indirectly (for authenticated encryption)  through  cryptsetup." This would seem to suggest that configuring dm-integrity with `cryptsetup`/dm-crypt provides more functionality than just putting one on top of the other. Your point about using `integritysetup --data-device` for an existing device is well taken, though.

Comment: LUKS 2/dm-crypt combination with integrity is called [authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption)
 and it is supported by `cryptsetup`, when creating the device you can use the `--integrity` option for that.

Comment: @VojtechTrefny I meant you do not have to reencrypt (and added that to my answer).